# Exporting Worksheet Title to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, title

I have VBA right now that loops through all of my worksheets and copy and pastes 4 charts per slide to my powerpoint presentation. I want to also be able to loop through all the worksheets and add the "title". ALL of my worksheets have a "title" in cell A1. Many also have another "title" in cell A60 or 61. I don't know if there is a way to make this work. I have ~ 50 slides and I don't want to manually type in titles for each slide.

Comment: Can you show any code you've tried so far?

Comment: From what i've seen online people have been using:
pSlide.Shapes(1).Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = stringMyTitle

but I don't even know where to begin with that. Also all of my titles are different so I can't just specify a generic title name.

My code works for copying and pasting the graphs, I just need titles now

Comment: @cdc949494 can you post your code that you use to export the 4 charts to slide

Comment: `SlideObject.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ws.Range("A1").Value` where `SlideObject` is a variable for `Slide*N*` and `ws` is a variable for `ws*n*`

Comment: I posted the code.

Comment: @ShaiRado it's posted

Comment: @ScottHoltzman , how do I use what you posted in the code I posted above?

Comment: @cdc949494 - are you even going to try to place it in? Or do you want to be spoon fed? Please make an attempt and if it's not working, let us know.